# Arduino YUN - in new hardware linino is causing the HTTP impossible

Tags: c++, linux, arduino, openwrt, arduino-yun

How to make sure with Linino HTTP is working? following code does not work with new latest Arduino YUN.

```
#include <HttpClient.h>
#include <Bridge.h>
void setup() { 
  //Bridge.begin(115200);
  delay(2000);
}


void loop() {
  HttpClient client;
  client.get("http://www.google.com/robot");
   .....
}
```

I also upgraded the firmware (https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software)  but no luck . Which one i should use to down-grade ( http://download.linino.org/linino_distro/master/ ) ? or how can i use HttpClient in latest boards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**it Works.**

Updated to the latest firmware and changed the code. Old code does not work. Fixed it!

**EDIT:**

- this following code is stable and working on latest Arduino YUN boards which has linino (doghunter password)

  `void setup() {
    delay(2000);
    pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
    Bridge.begin();
    digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
  }`
- When micro-USB to USB2.0 connects to PC the line Bridge.begin(250000); works

[image]

- When micro-USB to USB2.0 connects to adapter the line Bridge.begin(250000); works

[image]
[image]

- When micro-USB to fat-USB to USB2.0 to adapter. DOES NOT WORK

[image]